# Stop LocationManager Updates

Tags: android

I'm trying to have GPS coordinates sent to a text message.  This code works, but every time the GPS updates location, it tries to send a new text message.  I can't figure out how to stop the location updates.  This is what I have currently...I realize it may not be the most efficient way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

}

public void GPSDisable() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(mlocListener);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();

        double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        double longitude = loc.getLongitude();

        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", "5555555555");
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Location:"+latitude+","+longitude);
        GPSDisable();
        startActivity(smsIntent);

    }


    @Override

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

    {

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: if you stop the update the location than how you sending the message. The LocationListener was implement for the location update event whenever the location was change the onLocationChange() will be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set two global variables latitude and longitude.
This variables would be updated every onLocationChanged. You cannot change this comportament, but you can get out from there the sending of sms.

I would send the sms on a timer after 5 seconds let's say.

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", "5555555555");
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Location:"+latitude+","+longitude);

    startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    }, 
    5000 );
```

And your onlocation changed could look like this

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    longitude = loc.getLongitude();


}
```

Comment: Actually what I wanted was for a text message to be sent after a location fix is established.  I was able to get it to work by following another tutorial at...

http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example

But the other replies were also helpful, especially Dany's about using a timer, which will helped me with a similar project.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First I would advise you to have a look at [this article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29).

Having said this, generally you should "unsubscribe" from the location manager when you do not need any more updates. Typically, you subscribe for location updates in "onCreate" and unsubscribe in "onDestroy" when you need updates for as long as your Activity is 'alive'. 
Even better is to subscribe/unsubscribe when your activity is getting visible or hidden respectively (via "onResume"/"onPause" respectively). Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle) for details on the Activity's lifecycle.

Now, about your specific problem, it is not clear what is your desired behavior. Do you want to send an SMS message every time the location changes? Or only when some time passes?

Assuming what you need is to send SMS whenever your location changes but not too often, I would suggest the following:
1. Register for location updates in "onResume" and unregister in "onPause".
2. Maintain some local variables that tell you which was the last time you sent an SMS message and what were the coordinates in it. These variables should probably persist Activity lifecycle events (e.g. when the Activity is destroyed, you should "store" these values, and restore them when you recreate it).
3. Whenever there is a new location update, check if it is too soon or too close (compared to the previous SMS) and if not send another message, updating the variables.

Having said these, please note that this will work for as long as your Activity is visible. If you need a similar functionality that does not require you to keep the Activity visible, I would suggest you use a BroadcastReceiver.